# ORDER BY datetime

Tags: mysql

```
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Will give me these as my results

```
2016-02-24 12:45:00
2016-02-20 18:00:00
2016-02-22 16:00:00
```

This doesn't make sense to me, how can it sort like this? My DB structure has the column set to "DATETIME" so I don't know if that affects it any, but how would I order this by date & time?

**EDIT #1:**

```
SELECT teams.t_id, teams.t_name, t.t_id AS t_id2, t.t_name AS t_name2, matches.m_id, matches.m_datetime, divisions.d_id, divisions.d_name, leagues.l_id, leagues.l_name 
        FROM matches 
            LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.t_id = matches.m_tid
            LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.t_id = matches.m_tid2 
            LEFT JOIN divisions ON divisions.d_id = matches.m_did
            LEFT JOIN leagues ON leagues.l_id = divisions.d_lid
        WHERE leagues.l_id = ?
        ORDER BY matches.m_datetime DESC, matches.m_id DESC
```

The query works, but it doesn't order for some reason.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e030c/1

Comment: Hmm, I get the same result when I do it on SQL Workbench... Maybe it's an issue with my query by itself? My query has 4 joins on it, and it's ordering by the first inner join query... I heard somewhere that it can only order where the WHERE clause is. Hopefully that isn't the case here :(

Comment: Added the query to the page.

Comment: Um, what's wrong with your query?  It's not going to produce the results you pasted above -- should produce the same in the fiddle I previously provided.  Some of those `outer joins` aren't needed btw...

Comment: Oh, I figured out my issue... It actually wasn't the query, or anything I did itself..... It was the dataTables that I was using from that site....

Comment: amend the question please, indicate its over with so nobody wastes any more time here - or better delete it (I think you can do that)